# JQuery mutliple ids selectors with var

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So i want to program Memory for a school project.
I want 2 cards to become invisible via `.css("visibility", "hidden")` but only one card becomes invisible and the other stays visible, until i pick another 2 cards.

keep in mind im awfull at programming:

```
$("#card"+card_id1 "#card"+card_id2).css("Visibility", "hidden");

$("#card"+card_id1).css("Visibility", "hidden");
$("#card"+card_id2).css("Visibility", "hidden");
```

were my attempts.

Any idea how i can assign the visibility to both `#card` at the same time with a var on them?

edit:

`

```
/*
$(".card_field").click(function(){
    clicked++;
    if(clicked <= 2)
        {
            card_id1 = $(this).attr("value");
            $(this).flip(true);
            clicked++;
        }
    else{
        card_id2 = $(this).attr("value");
        if(card_id1 == card_id2)
            {
                $("#card"[ + card_id1]).css("visibility",  "hidden");
                $("#card"[ + card_id2]).css("visibility",  "hidden");
            }
        else{
            $("#card" + card_id1).flip(false);
            $("#card" + card_id2).flip(false);
        }
        card_id1;
        card_id2;
        alert(card_id1 + " " + card_id2);
    }
});
*/

$(".card_field").click(function(){
    if(clicked != 1)
        {
            card_id1 = $(this).attr("value");
            $(this).flip("toggle");
            clicked = 1;
        }
    else
        {
            card_id2 = $(this).attr("value");
            $(this).flip("toggle");
            clicked=2;
        }

    if(clicked==2)
        {
            if(card_id1 == card_id2)
            {
                setTimeout(function(){

                });
                $("#card"+card_id1 + ", " + "#card"+card_id2).css("visibility", "hidden");
                card_id1 = "";
                card_id2 = "";

                clicked =0;

            }
            else
                {
                    $("#card"+card_id1).flip(false);
                    $("#card"+card_id2).flip(false);
                    card_id1 = "";
                    card_id2 = "";
                    clicked=0;
                }

        }
    else
        {
        }

});`
```

the commend part was my previous attempt.

sry for the missing edit, thought it wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: `$("#card"+card_id1 ,  "#card"+card_id2).css("Visibility", "hidden");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a comma in there. Just make sure it's being built properly as part of the string:

`$("#card" + card_id1 + ", " + "#card" + card_id2).css("visibility", "hidden");`

When specifying more than one selector, your end result should look like a string of selectors separated by commas, like this:
`$("#card-123, #card-abc")`

Also, `Visibility` isn't a property name, `visibility`, however, is! So make sure to type property names in lowercase, and that should help out too.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!
But i still have the problem, that only one card turns invisible and the others stays open.
Any idea to that problem?

Comment: Sure thing! Too bad it isn't working exactly right yet - and you have this line just as I put it? `$("#card" + card_id1 + ", " + "#card" + card_id2).css("visibility", "hidden");`? Honestly for things like this I usually prefer to use utility classes with names like `is-hidden` to apply to groups of elements, but that may be more than you're wanting to do for this.

Comment: Yes, i copied it just so i dont type it wrong aswell. I have the feeling that the `.flip()` animation of the 2nd card too long is, so hidden won't apply to it.

Comment: Oh, seems like you have more going on there than what your original question shows. Could you update your question to add what you have now, and also add anything else you're doing to those elements around it?